# Can I clear a specific letter in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am using Python turtle to draw letters across a screen, and I want to be able to clear specific ones.

I know that I can use `.clear()`, but that will clear all of the letters that has been written with the `.write()` function. Everything in my code seems to be working, and I am able to send the value (letter) that I want to change, but I don't know how I would delete it. I know that I can also write over the letter with a different color, but that wouldn't work with my scheme, and it also slows down the code a lot (I have done it before). Would I have to use multiple turtles for the number of letters on the screen?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, it doesnt, the `.undo()` would remove the last letter, but that isnt always the letter that should be cleared. Also, with `.clear()` it clears all of the data, and that will clear all of the letters, unless I make multiple turtles, which is a viable option, but I want to see if there are any others options.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have asked whether you could do this by using multiple turtles (or at least have made it more clear that you don't want to do this).

Comment: In any case, these questions are currently basically asking the same, and if there is another possibility, it could as well be an answer to the other question.

Comment: How are you drawing these letters, please? A [mcve] would go a long way to make this actionable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruling out the *turtle per letter* option, the next thing that comes to mind is using a fixed width font and rewriting the string with `tracer()` turned off (i.e. explicit updates):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ('Courier', 24, 'normal')

PHRASE = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

VOWELS = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}

def write(x=None, y=None):
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.write(PHRASE, align='center', font=FONT)
    screen.update()
    screen.onclick(rewrite)

def rewrite(x=None, y=None):
    consonants = ''.join(' ' if letter in VOWELS else letter for letter in PHRASE)
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.write(consonants, align='center', font=FONT)
    screen.update()
    screen.onclick(write)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

write()

screen.mainloop()
```

Click on the screen and all the vowels will disappear and reappear.